# Why is there so much difference between the accuracy of model prediction and training accuracy?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, mnist, resnet

Here is my code:

dataset: mnist;

model: resnet

based on tensorflow 1.15.0

During resnet model training, I noticed this behavior in my experiment. The training loss decreses, and training accuracy is incresing, round 0.99. But during testing, the test data's accuracy is 0.06, which is so different from training accuracy.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)

np.random.seed(2020)
tf.set_random_seed(2020)

class ModelVGG11(object):
    def __init__(self, data_train, data_test, session):
        self.data_train = data_train
        self.data_test = data_test
        self.sess = session

        self.num_epochs = 10
        self.num_class = 10
        self.batch_size = 256
        self.learning_rate = 0.01

        self.__def_placeholders()
        self.__initial_dataset()
        self.__def_model()
        self.__def_loss()
        self.__def_optimizer()
        self.__def_metrics()

    def __def_placeholders(self):
        self.inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 224, 224, 1), name='model_input')
        self.label = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(None, ), name='model_label')
        self.is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, shape=(), name='is_training')
        self.handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=())
        self.global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)

    def __initial_dataset(self):
        def __image_resize(data):
            image = tf.cast(data['image'], tf.float32)
            # image = image / 255
            image = tf.image.resize_image_with_pad(image, 224, 224)
            return image, data['label']

        self.data_train = self.data_train.map(__image_resize).shuffle(buffer_size=1000).batch(self.batch_size).prefetch(1)
        self.data_test = self.data_test.map(__image_resize).shuffle(buffer_size=1000).batch(self.batch_size).prefetch(1)

        self.iterator_train = self.data_train.make_initializable_iterator()
        self.iterator_test = self.data_test.make_initializable_iterator()
        self.handle_train = self.iterator_train.string_handle()
        self.handle_test = self.iterator_test.string_handle()
        iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(self.handle, self.data_train.output_types, self.data_train.output_shapes)
        self.next_batch = iterator.get_next()

    def __res_block(self, inputs, out_channels, conv1x1=False, strides=1, name=None):
        with tf.variable_scope(name):
            outputs = tf.layers.Conv2D(out_channels, kernel_size=3, strides=strides, padding='same', activation=None, kernel_initializer=tf.glorot_normal_initializer)(inputs)
            outputs = tf.layers.BatchNormalization()(outputs, training=self.is_training)
            outputs = tf.nn.relu(outputs)
            outputs = tf.layers.Conv2D(out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation=None, kernel_initializer=tf.glorot_normal_initializer)(outputs)
            outputs = tf.layers.BatchNormalization()(outputs, training=self.is_training)
            # change input channels equal to out_channels
            if conv1x1:
                inputs = tf.layers.Conv2D(out_channels, kernel_size=1, strides=strides)(inputs)
            return tf.nn.relu(outputs + inputs)

    def __def_model(self):
        with tf.variable_scope('resnet'):
            # [batch, 224, 224, 1]
            inputs = tf.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=7, strides=2, padding='same', activation=None, kernel_initializer=tf.glorot_normal_initializer)(self.inputs) # [batch, 112, 112, 64]
            inputs = tf.layers.BatchNormalization()(inputs, training=self.is_training)
            inputs = tf.nn.relu(inputs)
            inputs = tf.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=3, strides=2, padding='same')(inputs) # [batch, 56, 56, 64]
            inputs = self.__res_block(inputs, 64, False, 1, 'res_bolock_1') # [batch, 56, 56, 64]
            inputs = self.__res_block(inputs, 128, True, 2, 'res_bolock_2') # [batch, 28, 28, 128]
            inputs = self.__res_block(inputs, 256, True, 2, 'res_bolock_3') # [batch, 14, 14, 256]
            inputs = self.__res_block(inputs, 512, True, 2, 'res_bolock_4') # [batch, 7, 7, 512]
            inputs = tf.reduce_mean(inputs, axis=[1, 2])
            outputs = tf.layers.Dense(units=10, activation=None)(inputs)
            self.outputs = outputs

    def __def_loss(self):
        y_true = tf.cast(tf.one_hot(self.label, self.num_class), tf.float32)
        loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_true, logits=self.outputs)
        self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
        tf.summary.scalar('loss', self.loss)

    def __def_optimizer(self):
        self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learning_rate).minimize(self.loss, global_step=self.global_step)

    def __def_metrics(self):
        y_pred_label = tf.arg_max(tf.nn.softmax(self.outputs), 1)
        # self.acc = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=self.label, predictions=y_pred_label, name='acc')
        self.acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(y_pred_label, self.label), tf.float32))
        tf.summary.scalar('acc', self.acc)

    def train_and_evaluate(self):
        # merge_summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
        # summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(self.summary_file, self.sess.graph)
        # summary_writer.add_summary(train_summary, step)

        self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        self.sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
        handle_train, handle_test = self.sess.run([self.handle_train, self.handle_test])
        for i in range(self.num_epochs):
            epoch_train_metrics = []
            try:
                self.sess.run(self.iterator_train.initializer)
                while True:
                    batch_x, batch_y = self.sess.run(self.next_batch, feed_dict={self.handle: handle_train})
                    loss, acc, _ = self.sess.run([self.loss, self.acc, self.optimizer], feed_dict={self.inputs: batch_x, self.label: batch_y, self.is_training: True})
                    epoch_train_metrics.append((loss, acc))
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                try:
                    self.sess.run(self.iterator_test.initializer)
                    while True:
                        batch_x_test, batch_y_test = self.sess.run(self.next_batch, feed_dict={self.handle: handle_test})
                        acc = self.sess.run(self.acc, feed_dict={self.inputs: batch_x_test, self.label: batch_y_test, self.is_training: False})
                except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                    print('epoch {} train minibatch loss and acc: {}, test minibatch acc: {}'.format(i + 1, np.mean(epoch_train_metrics, axis=0), acc))
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mnist_data = tfds.load('mnist')
    mnist_train, mnist_test = mnist_data['train'], mnist_data['test']

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        model = ModelVGG11(mnist_train, mnist_test, sess)
        model.train_and_evaluate()
```

And here is the result:

```
epoch 1 train minibatch loss and acc: [0.45032835 0.8764905 ], test minibatch acc: 0.0
epoch 2 train minibatch loss and acc: [0.06525008 0.9811669 ], test minibatch acc: 0.0
epoch 3 train minibatch loss and acc: [0.04049642 0.9874501 ], test minibatch acc: 0.125
epoch 4 train minibatch loss and acc: [0.02956291 0.99075246], test minibatch acc: 0.0
epoch 5 train minibatch loss and acc: [0.02403079 0.99252546], test minibatch acc: 0.0625
epoch 6 train minibatch loss and acc: [0.02128655 0.9933344 ], test minibatch acc: 0.0625
epoch 7 train minibatch loss and acc: [0.01614667 0.9947141 ], test minibatch acc: 0.0625
epoch 8 train minibatch loss and acc: [0.01534516 0.99461436], test minibatch acc: 0.0625
epoch 9 train minibatch loss and acc: [0.01119067 0.9964262 ], test minibatch acc: 0.125
epoch 10 train minibatch loss and acc: [0.0108306 0.9965314], test minibatch acc: 0.0625
```

I just want to know why this happen? Is there any error in my code?

Comment: It looks like you're training a resnet-like model from scratch on the mnist digits dataset. That's a _very_ large model for a pretty small dataset, so it's overfitting on the train data. You should try using a much smaller model with just a few convolution and pooling layers, no residual blocks.

Comment: @Swier I tried a smaller model, removed six resnet block and got the same result: training accuracy is around 0.9, but prediction accuracy is around 0.06. I think there exists some error in my code, but I can't find it. :(

Comment: Debugging code is somewhat out of scope for stackoverflow, but looking at your test accuracy, it looks like it's in multiples or 1/16th, so you're probably evaluating on only 16 samples. I suggest trying to fit and evaluate the model as bare-bones as possible, and get that to work, before building a class around it and working with batches etc.